# Tern stopped working! Request failed: ((wrong-type-argument url nil))

Tags: debugging, tern

> I just upgraded yesterday emacs from version 25.2 to 27.0.5. Now I am encountering this problem, any idea of how to fix it?

[image: Tern error]

> This happens in some tern functions I try to use: tern-get-docs, tern-ac-complete...

Comment: Please provide a full backtrace by using `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, reproducing the problem and copy-pasting the full backtrace into your question.

Comment: Ok, I followed your instruction, but I don't see more output.  "I am checking the "Messages " buffer

Comment: It should pop up a backtrace buffer when running into an error unless errors are suppressed.  In that case you'll have to study tern's sources to figure out how and change that so that you'll get a backtrace again.  Alternatively ask on the project's bug tracker.

Comment: Facing the same issues here. I opened an issue in the ternjs github issues tracker. Looks like updating to emacs master broke ternjs :(

Comment: Mmm I just downgraded emacs to version 25.2. I hope this gets fixed in the incoming days. The problem is that library 'url I guess. I dont really know how to debug emacs lisp.

Comment: Tern got updated in MELPA to fix this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is already solved by the tern's update in MELPA

[image: tern]